# Fill datagrid with dataTable wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

I got this table that I made with data from a text file.
Every line from the text I split to a array and then put it in the table,
now I want to bind the table to a `datagrid.`
Okay, I can do this by `datagrid.itemssource = table.defuealView`
But I want to make it so that when I change data in the datagrid, I can press a button, an all the data from the datagrid is exported out in a data table or a array.

how do I do this? always binded around the xml file. anyone that can point me the right way?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have it in a data table... have you tried writing it via

```
DataTable oDT = new DataTable();
// populated with your columns and data from whatever source
oDT.WriteXml( "C:\SomePath\YourXMLOutput.xml" );
```

Comment: i wanna take the table out with the changes done, an save every row over in a string[] 

like row[0] = string[0];

Sry if i didn't define my problem right.

Comment: @DaCh, the WriteXML writes everything in the datatable out to a new file in XML format.  Every Row, Every Column.  Reading IN XML is almost as easy too, if you include the xml schema along.  However... if that is NOT the case, do you just want a dump of every row, every column that is in your datagrid that is presented to the user?  And for each row, you just want it dumped as string... how to delimit the values between fields... what if date, numerics, strings that have commas?  Many things to consider.

Comment: the point was that i wanna take every row in the datagrid, an make it to a string[]. like i have found a workaround that can do it like i posted, but there most be a easyere way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a work around, its not the right way, but it works:

```
List<String[]> list = new List<string[]>();

foreach (DataRowView item in Datagrid.ItemsSource)
{
    DataRowView vivew = item;
    string[] line = new string[vivew.Row.ItemArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        line[i] = vivew.Row[i].ToString();    
    }

    list.Add(line);
}
```